# Did everyone live longer in the times of the older prophets?

Tags: science, scientific-proof, prophet-nuh

I've been looking at the ages of the prophets and I could understand if they were exceptions who could live much longer than the normal person but yesterday I read this about Prophet Nuh:

> [11:27] "But the chiefs of those who disbelieved from among his people said: We do not consider you but a mortal like ourselves, and we do not see any have followed you but those who are the meanest of us at first thought and we do not see in you any excellence over us; nay, we deem you liars."

Which implies that his long lifespan was a norm back then for the general population and this is clearly scientifically impossible so I'm very confused at the moment and it's making me question the validity of the Qur'an.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To me this reads like there's a clear mismatch between question title and content. As in the content you don't ask any question the answer of your question title is somewhat subjective and hard to answer in general for that the question would need a focus. This makes this question as is written a bad fit for our site. I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and at least check our [help] to learn more about our site and the stackexchange model.